# how to remove the space when the image is clipped using css

Tags: html, css

when clip property of the css then the image is clipped but the problem is, the clipped part of image reserve the space.Is there any way to remove that space after image is clipped.

HTML Code
// image with id: clip2

```
<img  id="clip2" src="image/background_right.png" style="height:100%; width:100%; max-width:350px; float:left;"/>
```

CSS Code
// code for clipping image

```
#clip2
    {
        position: absolute;
        clip: rect(0px, 150px,600px,0px);
    }
```

Comment: Please provide some code to demonstrate what is happening, and explain in detail what the desired behavior is.

Comment: <img  id="clip2" src="image/background_right.png" style="height:100%; width:100%; max-width:350px; float:left;"/>

Comment: it is using css,

#clip2
 {
     position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 150px,600px,0px);
 }

when i clip it the image is clipped but problem it leaves the space behind which i don't want

Comment: Please update your question with the code, formatting it properly, instead of posting it as a comment.

Answer (score 1):

`clip` (and the more recent `clip-path`) merely defines a path for clipping, it doesn't change the width/height of the element being clipped.

You can achieve what you want by using a div element with the size you want and set the image as a background image.

```css
#clip2
    {
        position: absolute;
      background-image: url("image/background_right.png");
      width: 150px;
      height: 600px;
    }
```

```html
<div  id="clip2"/>
```

Comment: i want to clip the left portion not the right portion, through your code it is clipping the right portion

Comment: you could use [background-position: right](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) or one of the other combinations to move the background image where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

The `clip` property [has been deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip), so it may never work reliably.

If you could, please add a bit more detail about your intended goals, and maybe a screenshot or a sample of your code so we can show you some alternatives which work with modern standards.

Comment: if it is depreciated then which is the other way to clip the image